# How to loop through multiple structures and perform the same operations [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, loops, concatenation, structure

I am trying to loop through multiple structures at once, extract variables of interest, and combine them into a single cell array. The problem: all of the variables have the same names. I have a working pseudocode--here it is:

Let's say I load i structures in my workspace. Now I want to loop through each structure, and extract time and position data from each structure.

First, I load my structures. Something like...

```
data_1
data_2
data_3
```

Then, I create appropriately sized cell arrays.

```
time{i,:} = zeros(size(structures));
position{i,:} = zeros(size(structures));
```

Finally, I loop through my structures to extract cell arrays and create a single array.

```
for i = 1:size(structures)
   time_i= data_i.numbers.time;
   position_i= data_i.numbers.position;
   time {i,:} = time_i;
   position{i,:} = position_i;
end
```

I want to end with a cell array containing a concatenation of all the variables in a single cell structure.

Could you please help convert my pseudo code/ideas into a script, or point me to resources that might help?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this code not giving you what you want? What errors are you running into?

Comment: Thanks, let me clarify my question: I don't know how to actually loop through "i" structures. In other words, how do I define "i", a changing numerical variable, as part of a structure name?

Comment: Ok, using eval should work. plus changing i to a string.

Comment: @excaza they are renaming a variable. How would you use dynamic here?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for what I was trying to do!

Comment: Great! was it excaza's comments or did eval work?

Comment: eval worked; I can see the potential of looking into dynamic field references,  but was not necessary here.

Comment: Yes, same here. Ok, great. Please accept my answers so others know it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
   eval(['time_',num2str(i),'= data_',num2str(i),'.numbers.time;'])
   eval(['position_',num2str(i),'= data_',num2str(i),'.numbers.position;'])
...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be a solution, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Will do, I will summarize my code and post it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely going to be better off loading your data internal to the loop and storing it into a cell or structure rather than trying to deal with iteratively named variables in your workspace. `eval` is, in nearly all cases, a significant code smell, not least of which because MATLAB's JIT compiler ignores `eval` statements so you get none of the engine's optimizations. `eval` statements are also difficult to parse, debug, and maintain.

An example of a stronger approach:

```
for ii = 1:nfiles
    tmp = load(thefilenames{ii});  % Or use output of dir

    trialstr = sprintf('trial_%u', ii);  % Generate trial string
    data.(trialstr).time = tmp.numbers.time;
    data.(trialstr).position = tmp.numbers.position;
end
```

Which leaves you with a final data structure of:

```
data
  trial_n
    time
    position
```

Which is far easier to iterate through later.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea, it will be helpful for when I have to access these variables again for further calculations later.

Answer (score 1):

My final script for anyone interested:

```
for i = 1:4 %for 4 structures that I am looping through
    eval(['time_',num2str(i),'= data_',num2str(i),'.numbers.time;']);
    eval(['position_',num2str(i),'= data_',num2str(i),'.numbers.position;']);
    %concatenate data into a single cell array here
    time{i} = {eval(['time_',num2str(i)])};
    position{i} = {eval(['position_',num2str(i)])};
end
```